# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'computation'

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow's [models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). I set up environment by seeing this web [site](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md). 
  .It was success　until Add Libraries to PYTHONPATH. But when I run `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py` in models/research directory,

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'computation'

error happens.Traceback says ,

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 21, in
>   
>       from object_detection.builders import model_builder   File "/Users/c/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py",
>   line 19, in 
>       from object_detection.builders import box_predictor_builder   File "/Users/myname/models/research/object_detection/builders/box_predictor_builder.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       from object_detection.core import box_predictor   File "/Users/myname/models/research/object_detection/core/box_predictor.py",
>   line 36, in 
>       slim = tf.contrib.slim   File "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py",
>   line 35, in **getattr**
>       contrib = importlib.import_module('tensorflow.contrib')   File "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/**init**.py",
>   line 30, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib import factorization   File "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/**init**.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.factorization.python.ops.gmm import *   File
>   "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/gmm.py", line 27, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator   File
>   "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/**init**.py",
>   line 87, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *   File "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/**init**.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *   File "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/**init**.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import estimators   File
>   "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/**init**.py",
>   line 297, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.dnn import DNNClassifier   File
>   "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import dnn_linear_combined   File
>   "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py",
>   line 31, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator   File
>   "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io import data_feeder   File
>   "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/**init**.py", line 21, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io.dask_io import extract_dask_data   File
>   "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/dask_io.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       import dask.dataframe as dd   File "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/**init**.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       from .core import (DataFrame, Series, Index, _Frame, map_partitions,   File
>   "/Users/myname/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py",
>   line 38, in 
>       pd.computation.expressions.set_use_numexpr(False) AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'computation'

I searched for this error and found this error causes broken pip. Therefore, I uninstall pip and install it again and i ran this command again, but same error happens.

What should I do to fix this?What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try upgrading dask:

```
pip install --upgrade dask
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2378